# Using switch case statement to change an image from a drop down list selection

Tags: javascript

My homework is to create a web page that displays an image and a drop down list, using a javascript switch statement. The code is written so that when a selection in the drop down list is made the image on the page will change to reflect the selection and an alert box will display a unique message for the selected image. I created switch case statements with a break between each case. The last case is a default with it's own alert message. I declared a global variable. In the body section I gave the select element id's and values for each option. You will see a function above the switch case statement commented out because it didn't work. None of the other cases nor their alerts display. But the code partially works. The page image and the drop down list displays. I just can't seem to get the image to change and the alert boxes to display. I've been at it for at least twenty hours yesterday and today. I could use some help. Suggestions? Since yesterday I've tried using multiple parameters in the function as well as in the switch. What happens is that the alert boxes stop displaying or go to default. I'm thinking the answer to change the page content i.e. the images in the drop down list may be in the form. I tried document.getElementById("pic").value and used it in the function and in the switch but it didn't work. So I'm stumped. Here is my changes. If anybody can give me some more hints, I'd appreciate. Like I said everything works except the page content is not changing in the switch.

Here is the link http://ciswebs.smc.edu/cis54/tyson_schweidel/SwitchSunGuy.htm
and the code:

The code sections are javascript which contain the switch case statement. The body sections contains the select element which is the drop down menu.
    
    
    
    
    var inobj,sunPic;
     function changepic(inobj, sunPic) {

```
 switch (inobj){

 case "0":
    sunPic ="1";
    alert("Please make a selection or go back to bed.");
    break;

  case "1":
    document.getElementById("pic").innerHTML = 2;
    alert("I am glad you are happy.");
    break;

  case "2":
   sunPic ="3";
    alert("I am sorry you are sad.");
    break;

  case "3":
   sunPic= "4";
    alert("It is great you are feeling cool.");
    break;

  case "4":
   sunPic= "5";
    alert("I hope you get past that soon.");
    break;
  default:
    alert("You need to fix something!");
    break;
  }
  } 


  </script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="items/Sun0.jpg" id="pic" alt="A funny face with question mark above.">
<p> Make selection to change the image.</p>
<form name = "sunPic" action="">
<select name="sunPic" onChange="changepic(this.value);">
<option  alt="funny face" value="0">Select</option>
<option  alt="happy face" value="1">Happy</option>
<option  alt="sad face"   value="2">Sad</option>
<option  alt="cool face"  value="3">Cool</option>
<option  alt="puzzled face" value="4">Unsure</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the select below -- I did not change it to make a different picture (since you did not give urls).  I'll that part of it to you -- but maybe this will help with the frustration.  NOTE:  There can only be one id of any given value on a page.

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KdebH/

```
<img src="items/Sun0.jpg" id="pic" alt="A funny face with question mark above.">
<p> Make selection to change the image.</p>
<select onChange="changepic(this.value);">
    <option  alt="funny face" value="0">Select</option>
    <option  alt="happy face" value="1">Happy</option>
    <option  alt="sad face"   value="2">Sad</option>
    <option  alt="cool face"  value="3">Cool</option>
    <option  alt="puzzled face" value="4">Unsure</option>
</select>


function changepic(inobj) {


    switch (inobj) {

    case "0":
        sunPicture = 1;
        alert("Please make a selection or go back to bed.");
        break;

    case "1":
        sunPicture = 2;
        alert("I am glad you are happy.");
        break;

    case "2":
        sunPicture = 3;
        alert("I am sorry you are sad.");
        break;

    case "3":
        sunPicture = 4;
        alert("It is great you are feeling cool.");
        break;

    case "4":
        sunPicture = 5;
        alert("I hope you get past that soon.");
        break;
    default:
        alert("You need to fix something!");
        break;
    }


}
```

Next steps:

for each case in the switch add code to

- find the image in the dom
- change the src attribute to point at the new image.

then you are done.

Comment: I could use a little more help on this. When I creating multiple parameters in the function the code still validates and I can still switch the alert boxes. But when I put multiple parameters in the switch (I think it's method) the alert box goes to default. All the time the code still validates. I'm still not getting the page content to change in any case. I'm reading on event handlers but it's all about if statements and I can't seem to translate that to switch case statement application.

Comment: You don't need multiple parameters for the function or the switch.

Comment: I added some hints to my answer about next steps.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, I will give you a hint that will get you thinking. What is the user changing the value of. You currently have the onchange on the body, but where should it really be?

Comment: Just a tad more help: onchange handler should be called differently - here's an example: http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/evhan_onchange.html

Comment: I put it in the select element but nothing happened. I really don't know where to put it at this point. The user is changing the value of the option. When the selection is made that's when the value changes.

Comment: I'm thinking that from what I just read that the onchange is called from function argument. But I don't have a function argument. I got to do more research. I like your answer. It's got me to thinking.

Comment: I'm making progress. Finally I got the alert boxes to display by initialing the global var inobj to = obj.selectedIndex.value. I removed the sunPictures, now I got to put them back and hope that changes the image onselect.